# Allow /category but disallow /category/subcategory

Tags: robots.txt

I am trying to allow `/category` in my robots.txt. Under the `/category` are `/subpages` and I would like to disallow anything after the `/category`.

I have already tried disallow `/category/subpage1` and `/category/subpage2` in the robots.txt, but since the subpages are growing and I don't want to edit the robots.txt time after time. Is there a way of doing this? Like adding a `/*` or so to the `/category`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Disallow: /category/
```

This blocks URLs whose path starts with `/category/`.

The URL with the path `/category` will keep being allowed to crawl, because it doesn’t have a trailing slash.